# Blank form processing page

Tags: php

I've written a registration system and now am working on the page to update the profile. Trouble is, when you submit the form, the processing page is absolutely blank. No text at all, no processing at all. Can anybody help troubleshoot?

**usercp.php**

```
<form action="doUser.php" method="post">
<strong>Email</strong><br>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $e; ?>" name="email"><br>
<strong>Please enter password to confirm</strong><br>
<input type="password" name="pass"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Go!"></form>
```

**doUser.php**

```
<div id="content">
<p>What is going on</p>
<?php

$e = $_POST["email"];
$p = $_POST["pass"];

echo $e;

if(isset($e)) {

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT pass FROM users WHERE id=:i");
    $query->bindParam(':i',$i);
    $query->execute();
    $result=$query->fetch();

    $password = $result['pass'];

    $check = password_verify($p, $password);

        if($check) {
            $query->prepare("UPDATE users SET email=':e'");
            $query->bindParam(':e', $e);
            $query->execute();
            header("Location: usercp.php");
            }
        else {
            echo "Incorrect password.";
            }

else {
    echo "You didn't enter a new email.";
}
?>
</div>
```

**core/init.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$db = new PDO('login data is fine');

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $i = $_SESSION['id'];
}
else {
echo "Please <a href='login.php'>log in.</a>";
$guest = True;
}
```

Comment: Don't just `echo` values to HTML forms, that's asking for Cross-site scripting (XSS). Use `htmlspecialchars` in this context. And `isset($e)` is useless, you'll get an error (or not) when you try to access `$_POST["email"]`. And leave out the quotes around `:e`, they'll generate an error.

Comment: Is your error reporting On?

Comment: Turn on error reporting, btw. check this code: `if(isset($e)) {` it should be `if(isset($_POST["email"])) {` because if `$e` is equal to `email@domain.tld` then `if(isset('email@domain.tld')) {` has no sense. Btw. and try to use mysqli instead of PDO, if you're not sure what is going on, mysqli would be easier way for you :)

Comment: Also, do this : `if(isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['pass']))` Currently, you're just checking if email is set.

Comment: Be aware that header should be sent before ANY html. Otherwise it results in fatal error "Headers already sent".

Comment: Indeed. The same is true for `session_start`. And I *think* you want to bind `$i` as an integer: `$query->bindParam(':i',$i,PDO::PARAM_INT)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can **not** use header() when you have already sent some data to user.

```
<div id="content">
<p>What is going on</p>
<?php

$e = $_POST["email"];
$p = $_POST["pass"];

echo $e;

if(isset($e)) {

    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT pass FROM users WHERE id=:i");
    $query->bindParam(':i',$i);
    $query->execute();
    $result=$query->fetch();

    $password = $result['pass']; //is this key exists?

    $check = password_verify($p, $password); //is this function exists?

        if($check) {
            $query->prepare("UPDATE users SET email=':e'");
            $query->bindParam(':e', $e);
            $query->execute();
            header("Location: usercp.php"); //because this won't work
            }
        else {
            echo "Incorrect password.";
            }

else {
    echo "You didn't enter a new email.";
}
?>
</div>
```

Moreover, add at the top

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

and you will know what's wrong

Comment: I don't know where the report will end up, and I don't have access to the php.ini file on my server?

Comment: When you add error_raporting and display errors in you scripts you will see the errros in you browser. You don't need access to php.ini.

Comment: In that case, the error reporting is showing nothing. Still only a blank page.

Comment: Have you removed the "header" function? I see there one more error. There should be "} else { echo You... " instead of "else {". You have forgotten about one "{".

Answer (score 0):

Try to set more error reporting on your doUser.php, as i believe that the issue is with header() being used after you try to echo data. Headers can only be used before any html...